# Why are the file sizes of translated powerpoint presentations so much larger than the original English?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2003

Why are the file sizes of my translated powerpoint presentations so much larger than the original English versions?  I checked for text and graphic duplication and/or overwrite, and am not finding enough to explain the phenomenon.  And how can I reduce the bloat?

Comment: translated to what with what tool/method?

Comment: @Mat: The original English PowerPoints are distributed to translators, who are just supposed to be replacing the text with the appropriate translations. There is no other software used. Common languages include French, Spanish, Italian, Japanese (Kanji), Norwegian, Dutch, and Mandarin Chinese--these are the ones we have the most trouble with bloating.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  It is actually a combination of behaviors: multiple masters, conversion from 2007 to 2003, and the fact that there are many languages that use a whole lot more words than English does to say exactly the same thing.  Add that to the overwrite of text and graphics, and I think I have found most of the answer.